# fonspec font shape undefined

Tags: fontspec

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{/local/path/to/cienfuegos}[ Extension=.ttf ] \begin{document}
\begin{itemize} \item HellO \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

---

```
/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape TU//home/r' undefined
(Font)              using TU/lmr/m/n' instead on input line 11.

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).

t
l.11 ^^I]
```

Advice of changes to make please?

Comment: That's the default `fontspec.cfg` file. You *don't* need to copy it anywhere. But the error has nothing to do with it. Please, add some code that shows the issue.

Comment: as I said in github when you posted there, you have shown no information to allow anyone to help. You need to show an example

Comment: Do you actually have the words “line 11:” in your file, not commented out with a `%`?

Comment: You can edit your post using the `edit` link at the bottom left to add the example.

Comment: \documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{/local/path/to/cienfuegos}[ Extension=.ttf ] 
\begin{document} 
\begin{itemize} 
\item HellO 
\end{itemize}
\end{document} 
command terminal:xelatex test.tex 
'line 11' added manually to show relation to error

Comment: "line 11' added manually" don't do that. (a) it means no one can use the file to reproduce the error (b) the small fragment of log you show showed the error was not in `fontspec.cfg` but line 11 of some code you had not shown.

Comment: the code you posted _still_ does not produce the error you show as you have deleted `/home`  the argument should _not_ have a path, possibly be `\setmainfont[Path=/a/b/c/]{cienfuegos.ttf}`

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
\setmainfont{<fontname>}[<options>]
```

TeX (either XeTeX or LuaTeX) wants in the mandatory argument something it can fully interpret. It can be a file name (but not with a path) or the PostScript name of a font present on your system.

For instance, on my system I can do

```
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
```

because it is known as an internal font name to the OS; interaction with the system libraries also makes it possible for TeX to guess also the fonts to associate with italics and boldface.

The mandatory argument can als be a file name with extension and in this case TeX will look for it in the relevant directories of the TeX trees.

If you want to load a font in a nonstandard directory, use the `Path` key:

```
\setmainfont{cienfuegos}[
  Path=/path/to/,
  Extension=.ttf
]
```

Suppose your font files follow nonstandard naming conventions, so you have `bizarre.ttf` for upright medium shape, `bizarrei.ttf` for italic, `bizarreb.ttf` for boldface and `bizarrebi.ttf` for bold italic. You can do

```
\setmainfont{bizarre}[
  Path=/path/to/,
  Extension=.ttf,
  UprightFont=*,
  ItalicFont=*i,
  BoldFont=*b,
  BoldItalicFont=*bi,
]
```

where the `*` will be replaced by the mandatory argument.